# Facebooks GraphQL object likes endpoint returning "Tried accessing nonexisting field (likes) on node type (Post)"

Tags: facebook, rest, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I am trying to access the likes per post within a group on facebook. I am an admin of the group and of the app I have created.
I can access the feed which includes the post messages, creation date, comment count, sub comment count, the comment message.
Plenty of field values are accessible.

Example of GET end point below (which works as expected):

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{group-ID}/feed?fields=link,caption,description,message,message_tags,comments.summary(true).limit(50){message}, created_time&access_token={Access-Token}
```

Even when trying to access the endpoint specifically for likes, I get the error message. This was my last resort to query each post using its object-ID but is in no way the ideal situation.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v6.0/{object-id}/likes
```

I get the same error message as if I try to add "likes.limit(0).summary(true)" to the main feed query field values.

```
  "error": {
    "message": "(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (likes) on node type (Post)",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 100,
    "fbtrace_id": "AGvN2KcMhKsuR7MxeUTxDZR"
  }
}
```

I must be missing something simple here because to allow me to retrieve comments, sub comments and the number of likes per comment should provide me with adequate rights for post likes.

Comment: PROBLEM SOLVED:!
likes has become reactions.
Solution: reactions.limit(0).summary(true)

Answer (score 1):

Likes have become "reactions".

Use this instead:

```
reactions.limit(0).summary(true)
```

as per OP NeemaB's [own comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61534546/solved-facebooks-graphql-object-likes-endpoint-returning-tried-accessing-non#comment108863679_61534546) to the question.